# Delete a ~$filename.docx from terminal with rm command

Tags: macos, terminal, ms-word, echo, rm

I found on my desktop directory a file named “~$ew Digital Card.docx” that’s invisible outside terminal. It’s a crash log file for a deleted word file named “New Digital Card.docx”.
To remove it first I tried `echo` with double quotes:

```
echo “~$ew Digital Card.docx”
```

output: ~ Digital Card.docx

```
cd Desktop/
rm ~\ Digital\ Card.docx
```

and then `echo` with single quote:

```
echo ‘~$ew Digital Card.docx’
```

output: ~$ew Digital Card.docx

```
cd Desktop/
rm ~$ew\ Digital\ Card.docx
```

but in both cases I got *"No such file or directory"* error..I get wrong with *rm* syntax? What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `rm -rf './yourmask'`

echo is just a toy, tried `ls -la` ?

read filelist, think about your mask and retry again.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I typed `ls -la` and find the correct statement for rm, then I typed `rm -rf 'correct filename.docx'` and I deleted it! But what is "yourmask" precisely?

Comment: You can try *.docx~ because if the doc is opened by openoffice, the workstate would be placed like this style. So you are able to cleanup a set of lost states to remove.

Comment: If you do open a document, the savestate shadow copy will be created from the office program. You can use a filename or a set of files in your mask. There are wildcards allowed. So you can say *.docx~ as mask to delete all files, that ends on 'docx~' ...

Comment: Ok, now I get it! Thanks for the help and the further explanation. Solved!

Comment: Good luck and happy hacking! :)